# Making Javascript toggle draggable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I have this script which is working fine:

```
  $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
   id = $(this).attr('toggle');
   $('.text').not('#' + id).hide();
   $('#' + id).show();
  });


   <a class="clickMe" toggle="first">Text 1</a>
       </br>
   <div id="first" class="text"> - This text will be toggled</div>

   <a class="clickMe" toggle="second">Text 2</a>
   </br>
   <div id="second" class="text"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

Please check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/53/)

but now I'm trying to do two things:

1. if clicked anywhere on the screen, toggled text should be disappeared and should come back to original position.
2. Text which is toggled should be draggable on the screen also need to add a closing button.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: remove `.show()` and use `.toggle()` Instead of it...

Comment: i tried that method but not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a.clickMe').click(function () {
   id = $(this).attr('toggle');
   $('#' + id).toggle();

});​
```

see [edit](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/56/)

```
 $('a.clickMe').draggable();
```

now see [draggable](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/59/)

Comment: i tried this .. but its not working...if we click on anywhere on the screen toggled should be disapper..but its not happeneing

Comment: thanks alot for trying dear... but one small issue with draggable ...only text which is toggled that should be draggable...anyways we can fix.. that.. well is there a way we can add close button  which will close draggable <div> ???